# How can I use Doctrine without caching results in a functional controller test?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is my scenario. We have written functional tests in symfony 2, where the test setup boots the kernel:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();
    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();
    $container = static::$kernel->getContainer();

    $this->doctrine = $container->get('doctrine');
    $this->em = $this->doctrine->getManager();

    self::setupTestData();
}
```

the last step is calling a routine that setups up test data. It passes the entity manager $this->em to that routine. This all works as expected, and the test data is available to the code in the controllers.

The controllers update some of the same entities, so in the test I use the same entity manager to fetch this data and verify the results. For the record, the UI does not have these fields available, they are used by a different code base, so we are forced to load the entities in the test and verify that way. like:

```
$repository = $this->doctrine->getRepository('MyBundle:Namespace\AutoSearch');
$autoSearch = $repository->findBy(array('Autosearch_ID' => $this->autoSearchId));
//verify expected values
```

Using either findBy or DQL I only get the *original* data from the test setup, not the updated data modified by the controller. If I use SQL, I can see the modified data. Why? Entity tracking by different entity manager in the test and controller? Caching?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
$this->em->clear();
```

to clear your entity manager, before accessing your (updated) data.  This will force the entity manager to clear any references it may have had to previous objects, and will reload them from your connection.  This should show the updated data.